# About the adress arithmetic in C

Tags: c

It's from a elementary question from the very beginning of MIT6.s081, Why does the fifth
printf's result is:

```
5: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 128144, a[2] = 256, a[3] = 302
```

I really can't imagine how 128144 comes!

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(void)
{
    int a[4];
    int *b = malloc(16);
    int *c;
    int i;

    printf("1: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);

    c = a;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        a[i] = 100 + i;
    c[0] = 200;
    printf("2: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c[1] = 300;
    *(c + 2) = 301;
    c[3] = 302;
    printf("3: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = c + 1;
    *c = 400;
    printf("4: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = (int *)((char *)c + 1);
    *c = 500;
    printf("5: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
           a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    b = (int *)a + 1;
    c = (int *)((char *)a + 1);
    printf("6: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps ask yourself where in `a` is `*c = 500;` storing its value. Which means you have to answer where in `a` does `((char *) c + 1)` point?

Comment: You are casting `c` to a `char *` (size 1) and increase that `char *` by 1.
Meaning that it now points to a 'shifted' version of `a` (shifted by one byte). Add endianess  to that and you will get your result.

Comment: I have no idea what the question says exactly and what its authors envisioned as the correct answer, but the program has undefined behaviour and is likely to crash on a platform that enforces alignment requirements.

Comment: Unrelated, `printf("1: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);` invokes UB. The value of `c` is never set to a determinate value at this point. it is neither initialized nor assigned.

Comment: It's my first time to ask in stackoverflow and i'm thankful for all the generous replies! Thanks a lot!`

Comment: Yeah, c is not initiated, and the output is the address of the variable c

Comment: Close but wrong. In first print, `c` is uninitialized. But it does not print the address of the variable `c`. Instead it prints the indetermined content of `c`. That is, it prints the address where `c` points to. With `c` being uninitialied, that is no valid address as you already know. On the other hand, printing the address of `c`, i.e. `&c` woule be well defined and not cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `4: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 400, a[2] = 301, a[3] = 302`

The binary value of the array pointed by `a` and `c` is as following:

```
            a
            c
C8 00 00 00 | 90 01 00 00 | 2D 01 00 00 | 2E 01 00 00
```

After    `c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);`

```
            a
            |    c
            |    |
C8 00 00 00 | 90 01 00 00 | 2D 01 00 00 | 2E 01 00 00
```

After     `*c = 500; // 500 = 0x000001F4`

```
            a
            |    c
            |    |
C8 00 00 00 | 90 F4 01 00 | 00 01 00 00 | 2E 01 00 00
```

So `a[1] = 0x0001F490; a[2] = 0x00000100;`
And `0x0001F490 = 128144, 0x00000100 = 256`.

Answer (score 1):

A standard integer is 4 bytes in width, meaning that, in memory, your 500 will look like this (assuming Big endian): `0x00 0x00 0x01 0xF4`.

If you do `c + 1`, with `c` being an `int *` you are actually moving the pointer by these four bytes.

By casting `c` to a `char *`, you change the step width of the pointer to `1`, meaning that it will now point to this location: 0x00 **0x00** 0x01 0xF4

By writing your 500 to that value, the same four bytes will now look like this: `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01` (the remaining 0xF4 will be written to the next integer).

I am now assuming that your machine is little endian, meaning the bytes are 'reversed'.

`0x90 0xF4 0x01 0x00`
The 0x90 is leftover from the assignment of 400 in the previous iteration and by putting them all together, you get 0x01f490 or 128144.